# getGeneratedKeys() doesn't work with JNDI in WildFly with Firebird

Tags: java, jndi, wildfly, firebird, jaybird

I was using getGeneratedKeys() with direct class invocation like this:

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
        String sql = "jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:e:\\COMPLEXO140116.FDB?defaultResultSetHoldable=True&encoding=WIN1252";
        return DriverManager.getConnection(sql, "SYSDBA", "masterkey");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new SQLException("Driver nao localizado.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception("Erro na base de dados." + e.getMessage() + " fim msg");
    }
}
```

and it was working fine, but after I changed to

```
public class ConnectionFactory {

    private static DataSource dataSource;

    static {
        try {
            dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:jboss/Firebird");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError("'jndifordbconc' not found in JNDI");
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }

}
```

It stops working giving the error:

> org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriverNotCapableException: Generated keys
>   functionality not available, most likely cause: ANTLR-Runtime not
>   available on classpath

I'm using WildFly 10, Firebird 2.5.5, Jaybird 2.2.9. antlr-4.5.2-complete.jar is present on buildpath, perhaps this is not the cause since it was working before change to JNDI way. And wildfly carries it's own antlr 2.7.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely one of classloading. When you use `DriverManager.getConnection`, the connection is created in the context of your application, but when you use the datasource, the connection is created in the context of the application server, and not your current application. So if the antlr-runtime is not available in the classpath of the application server itself, the generated keys functionality is not available.

Jaybird requires the antlr-runtime version 3.4, which is - as far as I know - not part of antlr 2.7.7. The antlr-complete version 4.5.2 contains the classes compatible with antlr-runtime 3.4 (interestingly enough, the antlr-runtime 4.5.2 doesn't!), so if these classes are part of your application, then that would explain why it does work when creating the connection inside your application.

To get it working when creating the connection from JNDI, you need to add the antlr-runtime to the module descriptor of Jaybird (either as a dependency, or as a resource).

The configuration (as originally [added](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35787445/4) to the question by [erickdeoliveiraleal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2882383/erickdeoliveiraleal)):

I created a folder with antlr-complete inside and with a new module.xml with the following code:

```xml
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.antlr4">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="antlr-4.5.2-complete.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

and added `<module name="org.antlr4"/>` in the Firebird module.

Comment: @erickdeoliveiraleal Any objections if I move your edit to your question to my answer?

Comment: Thank you, same issue resolved with wildfly 18 and Jaybird 3.0.8